# Можно ли использовать set к специфичным объектам?

Tags: python, list, set

Итак, сейчас я изучаю питон. И, узнав о такой прекрасной функции, как set, которая позволяет узнать "разницу" массивов, я понял, что это именно то, что мне нужно. Приведу пример

```py
a = [3,2,4,1]
b = [2,3,4]
a = list(set(a) - (set(a)-set(b))
print(a)
```

После выполнения данная программа выведет массив [2,3,4]. Я захотел попробовать применить set к листу, элементы которого содержат написанный мною класс

Выглядит примерно так

```py
list1 = list(set(list1) - (set(list1) - set(list2))
print(list1)
```

Но питон выдаёт мне ошибку unhashable type. Функции для сравнения двух экземпляров класса == и != написаны

Comment: unhashable type - значит отсутствует метод `__hash__`

Comment: @insolor я сделал `class A: pass` без метода `__hash__`, но `set([A()])` всё равно замечательно работает. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: (сам спросил, сам ответил: при наличии `__eq__` работать перестаёт, чёт мда)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка `unhashable type` означает, что не реализован метод `__hash__` (но реализован метод `__eq__`), либо вы пытаетесь положить в `set` изменяемый стандартный объект (например сделать `set` из списков). Дело в том, что `set` внутри реализован как [хеш-таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), поэтому чтобы положить ваш объект в `set`, интерпретатору нужно знать, как посчитать он него хеш.

Пример реализации хешируемого объекта:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "A({})".format(self.x)

print(set([A(1), A(2)]))  # {A(1), A(2)}
```

Если метод `__eq__` не реализовать, то сравниваться будет по id объекта (поведение унаследованное от класса `object`).

Чтобы два разных объекта внутри `set` слились в один, они должны быть равны и по `__hash__`, и по `__eq__`. Пример "сломанной" реализации, когда два любых объекта класса `A` внутри set-а будут считаться одним и тем же объектом:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __hash__(self):
        return 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return "A({})".format(self.x)

print(set([A(1), A(2)]))  # {A(1)}
```